# Redirect to other page on swipe at window

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I try to redirect to another page if the users swipes left.

I included these two files:

```
<script src="js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

I tried it like this:

```
$(document).ready(main);

function main()
{
    $("window").on( "swipeleft", swipeleftHandler );

    function swipeleftHandler( event )
    {
        window.location.href = "index.php";
    }
}
```

But nothing happens at all. No errors are thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $( "body" ).on( "swipeleft", swipeleftHandler );

    function swipeleftHandler( event ){
    window.location.href = "index.php";
    }
});
</script>
```

Not in the function(main), in the php page

Comment: This worked, but why does it not work with `window` ? Even my code works if i just replace `window` with `body`

Comment: I think because it works only with tag names... you can try with "html" and it works too. Hope that helps